# Android aviary forceCropPreset

Tags: java, android, android-activity, crop, aviary

I am using  Aviary for my project and I need to force crop the image as square when it's taken (forceCropPreset).

I found a sample in the aviary [website for the "WEB".](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/web/setup-guide#constructor-example) But I need to know how to do it for Android.

here is they sample for WEB:

```
editor.launch({
  'image': ...,
  'url': ...,
  forceCropPreset: ['My Size','2:1']  
});
```

It seems I need to create a configuration for aviary but I dont know how to so it, Does anyone knows ? Thanks